# Not able to plot wireframe with matplotlib 3d

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying following code from https://pythonprogramming.net/3d-graphing-python-matplotlib/

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
X, Y, Z = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[5,6,2,3,13,4,1,2,4,8],[2,3,3,3,5,7,9,11,9,10]
ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z)

plt.show()
```

However, I am getting following error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

I have tried converting list to `np.array` but still the error persists. Where is the problem?

Comment: I guess one should mention that the code in the link is simply wrong. `plot_wireframe` would need 2D arrays as input, while here you have 1D lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just some library version compatibility issue, try change `ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z)` to `ax.plot(X, Y, Z)`.

Comment: Yes it works. It is as 'line' is default for plot command. Thanks.